# How can I know what all clients have subscription to my graphql data?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-subscriptions, express-graphql

I need to know what all clients are watching what type of data in my subscription server. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can log all the queries/schemas that are being sent to the GraphQL server
2. from there you can check which objects and fields are being selected
3. as part of the request that was made, you should have an IP address or an API key that can be used to identify the client